# T-SQL extract image from Max(Date)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have pictures in a database which I now need to extract.  The image column is of type `varbinary(max)`.

I tried several examples using either a JOIN or subquery to no avail.  The query developed would work if it wasn't for the image.  Using `DISTINCT` and `MAX(date)` still can't eliminnate the older image. Many IDs have multiple pictures. Using the `Max(Date)` would extract the most recent date, but adding in the picture eliminates all the filtering.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Image, DateModified, GETDate()
 FROM images
WHERE 
   TYPE = 'B'

ID  Image  DateMod     Type

1   0x789  01-02-2014  B

1   0x791  11-12-2015  B   <-- this is a tgt record

2   0x675  12-01-2015  A

5   0x324  06-26-2015  B   <-- this is a tgt record
```

If I use `MAX(DateModified)`, that forces a `GROUP BY` and it still doesn't eliminate the older images.  I need the newest Type 'B' image for each ID. I am working on SQL Server 2012.

What I need for output is 
`image, ID, DateModified, TodaysDate (GetDate)`

Comment: what is your criteria for the tgt record.  is it a certain period of time or the top n records?

Comment: @H20rider "The newest Type 'B' image for each ID" - i.e. the `TOP 1` in date order per group (by id) and where Type = B.

Comment: @Dave see my answer. You are not using a `GROUP BY`, even though the `DISTINCT` clause can emulate it when used properly.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you want something like this.

```
with SortedResults as
(
    select ID
        , Image
        , DateMod
        , Type
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by DateMod desc) as RowNum
    from images
    where Type = 'B'
)


select ID
    , Image
    , DateMod
    , GetDate()
from SortedResults
where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: @Sean.Lange A funny thing occurred, your query to the SQL Analyzer used 5% less even though I distinctly remember the first time I ran the query that your query took a full second longer to show up in the results. I did some research on the phenomenon and found a very well-written [article](http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2009/6/4/partition-by-versus-group-by.html) about analytic functions vs the GROUP BY. the former ends up hogging CPU and Memory Costs though the IO is lowered (only one table read scan). The article is fascinating and challenged my initial perception. :)

Comment: @clifton_h - Even more interesting is that the book is about Oracle so any performance analysis is not relevant here because you are using sql server.

Comment: Sean, thank you for the solution.  It does retrieve the records I am looking for. I also tried the solution below and it produced 9 more records. So I am looking at that now for difference.  I like the CTE approach partitioning the records.  Nice job.

Answer (score 2):

Try following query

```
SELECT
  I.[Image],
  I.DateMod,
  GetDate()
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        ID,
        MAX(DateModified) AS DateModified   
    FROM 
        images 
    WHERE 
        [TYPE] = 'B'
    GROUP BY
        ID
) A INNER JOIN 
images I ON A.ID = I.ID AND A.DateModified = I.DateModified
```

Comment: This query produces the number of records I was expecting from my trials last week.  The solution above from Sean is a good solution too.  However it produced a result of 9 records less.  Analyzing that currently.  Both solutions are providing the results I need. Just have to determine if those 9 records are needed or not. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely twofold:

- 1) You are confusing the logical order of the clauses used in SQL Server.
- 2) Your `DISTINCT` is the culprit.

I suggest you study and memorize the [Logical order of SQL Clauses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) so that you understand logically how SQL Server is reading your prescribed query. For simplicity, start with the **Classic** list, which is used in many places.

```
Classic         Complete

FROM        |   FROM
WHERE       |   ON
GROUP BY    |   JOIN
HAVING      |   WHERE
SELECT      |   GROUP BY
ORDER BY    |   WITH CUBE, WITH ROLLUP
            |   HAVING
            |   SELECT
            |   DISTINCT
            |   ORDER BY
            |   TOP
```

Already we can see why your query is returning the results wrong, since SQL Server is **not** smashing the column sets together but rather smashing distinct **rows** across your columns.

Your example list:

```
ID  Image  DateMod     Type

1   0x789  01-02-2014  B    
1   0x791  11-12-2015  B   <-- this is a tgt record   
2   0x675  12-01-2015  A    
5   0x324  06-26-2015  B   <-- this is a tgt record
```

Has unique **rows** and therefore returns all of the records. Clearly, `DISTINCT` is the problem.

One solution is to keep your predicate the same and use the `GROUP BY` clause to smash sets of columns and use the `MAX()` aggregate function to return the largest value.

```
;WITH C AS
( SELECT ID
        , MAX(DateMod) AS DateModified
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) AS [Current_Time]
FROM   #Images
WHERE Type = 'B'
GROUP BY ID, Type)

SELECT C.ID, B.Image, C.DateModified, C.[Current_Time]
FROM C
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ID, DateMod, Image FROM #Images) B ON C.ID = B.ID
                                                        AND C.DateModified = B.DateMod
```

-- results

```
ID  Image           DateModified  Current_Time
1   0x3078373931    11-12-2015    07-16-2016
5   0x3078333234    06-26-2015    07-16-2016
```

Comment: You could use an `INNER JOIN`, too, depends on whether you want any potential empty rows (and thus a `NULL`) to return or not.